# Gmail filter sent to group but exclude if I am copied

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I am setting up filters in Gmail. I am part of a distribution group and I want any email coming to that group to be filtered and labelled. The issue is when some one sent an email to the group and CC or TO me I want that mail to be come to my inbox. I mean exclude when I am on TO or CC.

I had these in Outlook but cannot find in Gmail